# Variable isn't updating as expected

Tags: awk

I'm trying to find the county with the largest land area percentage from a sample. Then I'm trying to print the NAME of the county and land area PERCENTAGE.

## Finds county with the largest percentage of land.

```
BEGIN { FS="\t"}
BEGIN {mostland = 0} {countyname} {landpercent = $4 /($4+$3)} {if (landpercent > mostland) mostland = landpercent; countyname = $1}
END {if (NR) print countyname " has the largest percentage of land at " mostland "%"}

My test.txt
largest 10000   100 10
medium  5000    50  5
small   1000    25  1
```

It displays the correct percentage for "largest". But it returns "small" for the county name.

"small has the largest percentage of land at .0909%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a bit of a bracketing issue. `BEGIN {}` needs to setup the variables before each line. You were resetting per line. Also your `if ()` needed `{}` around both clauses.

Try this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t"; mostland = 0; countyname = ""} {landpercent = $4 /($4+$3)} {if (landpercent > mostland) {mostland = landpercent; countyname = $1}} END {print countyname " has the largest percentage of land at " mostland "%"}' infile.txt 
largest has the largest percentage of land at 0.0909091%
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and explanation. I wasn't aware of each action after the condition needed it's own {}.

Comment: @Tomarik - it doesn't, the `{}` goes around the **set** of actions, not around each individually. @dr - you misread what that second BEGIN is doing, it's just redundant, not harmful.

Comment: Make it `BEGIN { FS="\t" }
{ landpercent = $4 /($4+$3); if (landpercent > mostland) {mostland = landpercent; countyname = $1} } END{...}`.